# right usage of "so" in sentence

Tags: grammar

"Humans love being appreciated and enjoy this"
Wold it be correct if I used 'so' instead of 'this' like example below?
"Humans love being appreciated and enjoy so"

Comment: No. It would be completely weird, to the point of incomprehensibility. What makes you think the two are interchangeable at that point?

Comment: In the example sentence, ***this*** refers back to (and is syntactically/semantically equivalent to) ***being appreciated***. But I think it's bordering on nonsense to say ***Humans love being appreciated and enjoy being appreciated*** - it's just pointless repetition of the same statement twice in one sentence. I'm ignoring the possibility that what humans enjoy is ***the fact that they*** love being appreciated - the syntax would allow that interpretation, but it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Humans love being appreciated and enjoy that so much."

"Humans love being appreciated and so enjoy that."

Those are two ways you can express your idea.